# Does this sentence have a correct subject?

Tags: sentence-construction, subjects, subject-verb-agreement

> How many cars the company has are not important for the company's financial

Could you please clarify, is "How many cars the company has" the subject of the sentence above?

I am confused a bit.

Comment: This "sentence" does not appear to be grammatical or complete. Can you share where you found it and check that you have copied all of it correctly?

Comment: @Hakan I think it's debatable, but to me "How many cars the company has is not important for ..." sounds better. It would make me wait for the next sentence; something like "What's important is ...".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Tyler James Young points out, the sentence is incomplete: there is a noun or NP missing at the end, something like:

> ... not important for the company's financial **strength**, or **status**, or **balance sheet**.

Otherwise, yes: [How many cars the company has] is the subject of the sentence. It is, however, a singular subject, a quantity, not a plural one, so the sentence should read

> How many cars the company has **is** not important for the company's financial *whatever-it-is*.

ADDED:
Jolenealaska asks *why* it is singular, which is a very good question. *How many cars the company has* does not stand for the expression *X cars*, which would be plural, it stands for just the number, one number, which is singular. Imagine a conversation between the owner of the company and the accountant:

> ACCT: Now here, opposite 'fleet', you have entered '12'.
>   OWN:  Right, we have twelve cars! Up from ten last year!
>   ACCT: **That is** not important. **How many** you have **is** not important. Bob, you imbecile, I tell you this every year: the Internal Revenue Service doesn't care how many cars you have. They want to know the value of your fleet.

Comment: I started to say that, but deleted my answer because I couldn't say *why*. Yes, it's singular, but *how*?

Comment: I actually made it up :p, because I am studying sentence forms by creating an affirmative sentence starting with "how many"

Comment: You can ask, "How many is too many?" You use **is** because "how many" is singular as a subject. I'm a native speaker, but I don't know *why* that's singular. I just know that it is.

Comment: MBA types sometimes refer to a company's financial status as "the company's financials". I've never heard this used in the singular, "the company's financial", but then I'm not an MBA. (Thank you, God.)

Comment: @Jay I thought of including that but decided I should not be party to corrupting our students.